# Redirect to Login page using Next JS middleware, if no cookie present

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js

I am implementing an authentication in Next JS app. I need to get the cookie from browser and check the cookie in the Next js middleware. If there is no cookie present, I need to redirect the page to "/login" route. but the page is making continuous request in the middleware to get the page.

How to redirect the page if there is no cookie?

I tried the below code in `/middleware.js` (Using Nextjs 13)

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(req) {
  const cookie = req.cookies.get("token")?.value;
  if (cookie === undefined) {
    const url = req.nextUrl.clone();
    url.pathname = "/login";
    return NextResponse.redirect(url, req.url);
  }
}
```

and here is the request made by the browser
[image: nextjs middleware requests]

Comment: im not sure but this might help you 
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/response-helpers

Comment: I tried everything related to redirect mentioned in Next Js Doc but no use

Comment: Make sure to check that the current page is not the login page before redirecting. Otherwise you'll get the infinite redirect loop you're seeing.

Comment: A middleware will be executed for every HTTP requests, so also on assets files like images, js, css, service workers js ....
Use ```console.log({ pathname: request.nextUrl.pathname });``` inside your middleware to see every request and use [Hamza Khattabi response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74633661/11447191) to build your ```matcher```.

Answer (score 10):

You have to use matchers on your middleware.

You have unlimited redirections because since you don't have cookies, you are redirected to the login page --> call the middleware --> check the cookie --> cookie empty --> redirect to login --> vice versa.

Add this to your middleware file:

```
export const config = {
    matcher: [
        '/((?!_next/static|favicon.ico|login|).*)',
    ]
}
```

Every requests that comes from /_next/static, /favicon.ico and /login will be ignored.

More info on the NextJS documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#matcher

Comment: This should be the correct answer, with `matcher` you can filter the requests that will invoke the middleware. Default is every requests, also assets files like images and js.

Comment: Consider that ```/((?!_next/static|favicon.ico|login|).*)``` will **NOT** be invoked on root route `http://example.com/` because of the last `|`.
Use ```/((?!_next/static|favicon.ico|login).*)``` to invoke it also on root route.
I wanted to pointed out because is easy to miss.

Comment: I want to archive the same things but using the local storage or contact API. I have already used and set the status after login in to context API but it not used in middleware